# How to test for multiple features in Modernizr

Tags: javascript, jquery, detect, modernizr

I was wondering how you could test for multiple features in modernizr. I know you can do:

```
if(Modernizr.websockets) { // has websockets } else { // no websockets }
```

But I was wondering how to test for *multiple* features. I have tried many common JavaScript syntaxes and I've also google'd it and cannot seem to find an answer. The reason I'm asking is because what I think would normally work, isn't working.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
if((Modernizr.cssgradients)|(Modernizr.fontface)|(Modernizr.rgba)) { var pass = true; }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you know about the `&&` (logical AND) operator? `if ( x && y && z ) { ... }`.

Comment: Oooh, that may be it. My brain must not be working. So, `if(Modernizr.cssgradients && Modernizr.fontface){}` ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I think your brain is working fine `:)`, you just need to brush up on [JavaScript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually fairly new to JavaScript. I only use it when I need something, I don't just use it casually. But I will start working on it. Thanks!